# What is the most efficient way to sum a column grouped by ID within 6 months of date column in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, cursor, sum

I am trying to find employee [ID] and the first [used date] where [Qty] > 4 within a timeframe of 6 months [UsedDate]. If the employee goes longer than 6 months, I want the sum of the Qty to start over  but I cannot seem to figure out how to sum [Qty] of multiple rows where those Used Dates are only within a 6 month period and if that doesn’t apply, start at the next earliest UsedDate and see if the employee[ID] then meets the criteria.

I initially had the first query within the second part but it wouldn’t recognize the [UsedStartDate] and [UsedEndDate] that way.  I’m sure I’m doing something wrong so I broke it out but the SUM either returns the total of all rows (not what I want) or the sum of that row (also not what I want).

```
SELECT ID
    ,RowID
    ,UsedDate
    ,Qty
    ,UsedStartDate = UsedDate   
    ,UsedEndDate = DATEADD(month, +6, UsedDate)
    INTO #DateRange
FROM #CrazyMath 


;WITH Used1 AS (SELECT ID
     ,RowID
     ,UsedDate 
     ,RowNum = ROW_Number() OVER(ORDER BY ID, RowID) FROM #CrazyMath)  
                  -- order (needed?)
    SELECT q.ID
      --,q.RowID
      --,q.UsedDate
      --,UsedStartDate
      --,UsedEndDate
      ,SUM(q.Qty) OVER(PARTITION BY a.ID
          --, a.UsedDate
        ORDER BY a.ID
                          ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sumqty               FROM #CrazyMath q
    INNER JOIN #DateRange a
    ON a.ID = q.ID AND a.RowID = q.RowID


Output:
ID  Row UsedDate    Qty SumQty
1   1   2/12/2013   4   4
1   2   10/30/2013  4   8
1   3   7/30/2014   4   12
2   1   7/9/2012    1   1
2   2   7/17/2012   1   2
2   3   8/3/2012    1   3
2   4   8/27/2012   1   4
2   5   9/24/2012   1   5
2   6   10/12/2012  1   6
3   1   2/11/2014   4   4
4   1   10/17/2003  4   4
4   2   11/17/2003  4   8
4   3   12/18/2003  4   12
4   4   1/14/2004   4   16
4   5   2/6/2004    4   20
4   6   2/26/2004   4   24
4   7   3/25/2004   4   28
5   1   8/31/2010   1   1
5   2   9/7/2010    1   2
5   3   9/23/2010   2   4
6   1   10/29/2003  3   3
6   2   6/5/2006    8   11
6   3   6/25/2006   8   19
6   4   7/25/2006   8   27
6   5   8/24/2006   8   35
6   6   9/18/2006   8   43
6   7   11/14/2006  8   51
6   8   12/7/2006   8   59
6   9   12/19/2006  8   67
```

Employee 1 should not sum because the datediff between each UsedDate is > 6 months
Employee 2 should return the UsedDate where RowID = 1 (first date in group where total sum > 4 and total days < 6 months)
... Employee 6 should return UsedDate where RowID = 2 (first date in group where total sum > 4 and total days < 6 months)

Update - Also Tried
Sum by CASE but would only return a column or value, not a sum of the grouped rows (and this was by 180 days vs 6 months):
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Qty > 4
    OR (t2.Qty < 5 AND (t1.SumDays IS NULL OR t1.SumDAys < 180)) 
    THEN t2.Qty ELSE '0' END) as sum

Answer (score 0):

As part of your solution, try using a CASE statement inside the SUM, something along the lines of

```
SUM(CASE WHEN UsedDate > dateadd(m,-6,getdate()) THEN q.Qty ELSE 0 END)
```

I know that doesn't address your entire question, but perhaps it helps move in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you. I was just updating that I have tried that and perhaps it's how I'm writing it but it returns the value in Qty not a sum of multiple Qty rows (per employee) within the CASE clause dateadd.  Ex:  ID 1; Sum 4  ID 1; Sum 0  ID 1; Sum 0

Comment: Hm yes that makes sense now. Haven't written one of these in a while ;-). The CASE statement needs to be moved up into the CTE.